# Login with DocuSign REST API Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

/*I need to pass the header information*/
    header{
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication": "{\"Username\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"Password\":\"mypassword\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"the-super-long-key\"}"
     }
     /*****How do I pass the username, password, and integratorKey to docusign****/
     'I tested the parameters on the docusign site and they worked.

```
Dim sUrl As String = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v1/login_information?api_password=true&include_account_id_guid=true&login_settings=all"         


    Dim oRequest As HttpWebRequest
    oRequest = WebRequest.Create(sUrl)
    oRequest.KeepAlive = False
    oRequest.Headers.Add("Username", "abc@gmail.com")
    oRequest.Headers.Add("Password", "mypassword")
    oRequest.Headers.Add("IntegratorKey", "my-integrator-key")


    Dim oResponse As HttpWebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse   '*****FAILS****
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the official website [Authentication](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction%2BChanges/Authentication.htm):

```
oRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication",
            string.Format(@"<DocuSignCredentials>
                            <Username>{0}</Username>
                            <Password>{1}</Password>
                            <IntegratorKey>{2}</IntegratorKey>
                           </DocuSignCredentials>",
            "abc@gmail.com",
            "mypassword",
            "my-integrator-key"));
```

I cant't test because I dont have a valid account!

Comment: this worked!  oRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication",
            String.Format("<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{0}</Username><Password>{1}</Password><IntegratorKey>{2}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>", "abc@gmail.com", "my-password", "my-integrator-code"))

Comment: @GoldenLion No problem! Don't forget to mark this one as the Answer!

Comment: @GoldenLion theres a mark above the answer count, just click it and it will turn green!

Comment: Thanks for the instruction